# Creating Nested Objects on the Fly With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript coming from a Python background, where it's easy to created nested data using custom dictionaries and `.get` methods. What I'm trying to do is created a nested object of artist data that takes on this form: `artistDict[artist][albumName] = albumYear`. I need to create this object on the fly by iterating over an iterable of album objects. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
albumDict = {};
albums.forEach(function(item){
albumDict[item.artist][item.name] = item.year;
});
document.write(albumDict);
```

This doesn't work, which isn't surprising, since something like this wouldn't work in Python either. However, in Python I could use a `.get` method to check if an entry was in the dictionary and create it if not -- is there something similar, or any other utility that I could use to achieve my goal in JS?

Comment: You have to test whether the property exists and if it doesn't, initialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
albums.forEach(function(item){
    albumDict[item.artist] = albumDict[item.artist] || {};
    albumDict[item.artist][item.name] = item.year;
});
```

The first line in that function sets `albumDict[item.artist]` to a new object if it doesn't exist, yet. Otherwise, it sets it to itself.

Then, you can just set the year on the dict entry.

Answer (score 4):

This should work: (if the property doesn't exist you should initialize it..)

```
albumDict = {};
albums.forEach(function(item){
    albumDict[item.artist] = albumDict[item.artist] || {};
    albumDict[item.artist][item.name] = item.year;
});
```